# Is it possible to use Autohotkey with an Apple Mac Keyboard to translate OSX keyboard shortcuts to the Windows 7 equivalents on a PC?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, autohotkey, translate

If a seasoned Apple Mac user who had spent years learning the OSX keyboard shortcuts for the favorite applications was considering moving over to a Windows 7 or 8 PC and they wanted to translate that keyboard shortcut knowledge over too.

Would it be possible to use a genuine Apple Mac keyboard on the PC and use Autohotkey to translate the modifier keys to the equivalent PC versions following this table of translation:

Mac            PC
cmd/Apple      ctrl
ctrl           Windows/Start

So that every time i pressed the "Apple" key on the Mac keyboard it executed the "ctrl" key on the PC and every time i pressed the "ctrl" key on the Apple keyboard it executed the "Windows/Start" key on the PC.

I would like this to be a permanent feature without having to add any additional modifier keys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible.  You would need to run this script at startup. [**Source**](http://www.overclock.net/t/1231886/guide-using-the-apple-wired-keyboard-in-windows-7)

```
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
; #Include Apple Wired Keyboard.ahk  ; Required for Eject Button. See Source.
SendMode Input

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; NOTES
; --------------------------------------------------------------
; ! = ALT
; ^ = CTRL
; + = SHIFT
; # = WIN

; media/function keys all mapped to the right option key
RAlt & F7::SendInput {Media_Prev}
RAlt & F8::SendInput {Media_Play_Pause}
RAlt & F9::SendInput {Media_Next}
RAlt & F10::SendInput {Volume_Mute}
RAlt & F11::SendInput {Volume_Down}
RAlt & F12::SendInput {Volume_Up}

; swap left command/windows key with left alt
LWin::LAlt
LAlt::LWin ; add a semicolon in front of this line if you want to disable the windows key

; Eject Key
F20::SendInput {Insert}

; F13-15, standard windows mapping
F13::SendInput {PrintScreen}
F14::SendInput {ScrollLock}
F15::SendInput {Pause}

;F16-19 custom app launchers, see http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm for usage info
F16::Run Notepad
F17::Run calc.exe
F18::Run http://www.overclock.net
F19::Run cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

I have it in a Gist here, emulates almost all Mac shorcuts in Windows: https://gist.github.com/jitbit/e948cf198f54cbf3992c